# Is point-to-set distance function $C^\infty$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Q\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Then we define the point-to-set distance function as:
$$
d_Q(x) = \inf_{y \in Q} \| x-y\|
$$

It's continuous for every normal space (not only $\mathbb{R}^n$), but what's about $C^{1}$ or $C^\infty$?

Comment: What is $C^{-1}$$?

Comment: It's true in every metric space.  So if those are metric spaces, with metric induced from the norm, then yes.

Comment: @tetori, sorry it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance function is not differentiable in general. Consider the case $n=1$ - for $Q=\{0\}$, $d_Q(x)$ is same as the modulus function and is not even differentiable.

Comment: Ye, you are right. Thank you.